# Authorization From Command Line Using Token

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I can get authorization from browser,I use example from site and it's working.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

But I want use it on remote server, after executing above code it show message that I can use "command-line parameter" but I don't know how to use it?

I use example from this page: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

Comment: please add a reference to the documentation you are using.

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: The docs say: The sample will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.

Can you paste the response from the command line utility here (sanitize the url if it's there)?

Comment: _"If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter"_
I don't understand how rerun program with command-line parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line utility outputs:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=#########

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this application with the command-line parameter

--noauth_local_webserver

Authentication successful.
access_token: #######
```

Run the command line utility with the --noauth_local_webserver flag.

```
python get_oauth2_token.py --noauth_local_webserver
```